# Restrict color picker for free and then give more options with inAppPurchases

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Here's the code of color picker which I am using, Now I want to restrict colors in the color band of HUE from where user will pick up the color. (I am using only HUE band to pick colors keeping saturation and brightness high/max)

```
    @interface ILHuePickerView(Private)

-(void)handleTouches:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end

@implementation ILHuePickerView

@synthesize color, delegate, hue, pickerOrientation;

#pragma mark - Setup

-(void)setup
{
    [super setup];

    self.clipsToBounds=YES;

    hue=0.5;
    pickerOrientation=ILHuePickerViewOrientationHorizontal;
}

#pragma mark - Drawing

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // draw the hue gradient
    CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace=CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    float step=0.166666666666667f;

    CGFloat locs[7]={ 
        0.00f, 
        step, 
        step*2, 
        step*3, 
        step*4, 
        step*5, 
        1.0f
    };

    NSArray *colors=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], 
                     (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], 
                     (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], 
                     (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], 
                     (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], 
                     (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], 
                     (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], 
                     nil];

    CGGradientRef grad=CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (CFArrayRef)colors, locs);
    if (pickerOrientation==ILHuePickerViewOrientationHorizontal)
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, grad, CGPointMake(rect.size.width,0), CGPointMake(0, 0), 0);
    else
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, grad, CGPointMake(0,rect.size.height), CGPointMake(0, 0), 0);

    CGGradientRelease(grad);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Draw the indicator
    float pos=(pickerOrientation==ILHuePickerViewOrientationHorizontal) ? rect.size.width*hue : rect.size.height*hue;
    float indLength=(pickerOrientation==ILHuePickerViewOrientationHorizontal) ? rect.size.height/3 : rect.size.width/3;

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.5);
    CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(0, 0), 4);

    if (pickerOrientation==ILHuePickerViewOrientationHorizontal)
    {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, pos-(indLength/2), -1);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pos+(indLength/2), -1);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pos, indLength);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pos-(indLength/2), -1);

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, pos-(indLength/2), rect.size.height+1);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pos+(indLength/2), rect.size.height+1);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pos, rect.size.height-indLength);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pos-(indLength/2), rect.size.height+1);
    }
    else
    {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, -1, pos-(indLength/2));
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, -1, pos+(indLength/2));
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, indLength, pos);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, -1, pos-(indLength/2));

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, rect.size.width+1, pos-(indLength/2));
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width+1, pos+(indLength/2));
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width-indLength, pos);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width+1, pos-(indLength/2));
    }

    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
}

#pragma mark - Touches

-(void)handleTouches:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint pos=[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    float p=(pickerOrientation==ILHuePickerViewOrientationHorizontal) ? pos.x : pos.y;
    float b=(pickerOrientation==ILHuePickerViewOrientationHorizontal) ? self.frame.size.width : self.frame.size.height;

    if (p<0)
        hue=0;
    else if (p>b)
        hue=1;
    else
        hue=p/b;

    [delegate huePicked:hue picker:self];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self handleTouches:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self handleTouches:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self handleTouches:touches withEvent:event];
}

#pragma mark - Property Setters

-(void)setHue:(float)h
{
    hue=h;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)setPickerOrientation:(ILHuePickerViewOrientation)po
{
    pickerOrientation=po;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

#pragma mark - Current color

-(void)setColor:(UIColor *)cc
{
    HSBType hsb=[cc HSB];

    hue=hsb.hue;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(UIColor *)color
{
    return [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:1.0f brightness:1.0f alpha:1.0];
}

@end
```

My requirement is initially user should get restricted to 3 colors only then if they buy new colors they should get more colors.

So how to code it for inApp purchase because I will be implementing it for the first time. I can restrict the colors in the band via CGFloat locs[3] and initializing array only for 3 colors  initially but how should I code it keeping InApp purchase thing in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user picked a color:

1. check if user has bought in-app purchase (can use NSUserDefault to track). If so, proceed
2. Otherwise, check if the picked color is a free color. If so, proceed
3. Otherwise, bring up in-app purchase pop-up

Comment: Thanks aha !! I will start implementing it. If i will face any kinda of problem will ask u ..